# Which features does JavaFX 2 provide and how mature is the implementation compared to related technology like Java Applets or Silverlight?

Tags: java, silverlight, swing, applet, javafx

Which functionality will be shipping with version 2 and are there any additions known to be  planned for later versions?

Will it reuse parts of the Applet/WebStart technology which are a bit more mature now or is the browser integration technique completely new? Will it be possible to access the whole JavaSE library or is it limited to a subset like Silverlight?

What about the overall rendering speed and architecture? Is it comparable to Swing/AWT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a JavaSE library, so you can use the whole Java SE API.

You can use java webstart or addtional integration features too (javascript).

In the end its really a full featured java SE application or Applet, but not on swing, but on JavaFX.

But if you want, you can mix Swing and JavaFX too.